# Which is better, using a central ID store or assigning IDs based on tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, erp

In many ERP Systems (Locally) I have seen that Databases (Generally MYSQL) uses central key store (Resource Identity). Why is that?

i.e. In a database one special table is maintained for generation of IDs which will have one cell (first one) which will have a number (ID) which is assigned to the subsequent tuple (i.e. common ID generation for all the tables in the same database).

Also in this table the entry for last inserted batch details are inserted. i.e. when 5 tuples in table ABC is inserted and, lets say that last ID of item in the batch is X, then an entry in the table (the central key store) is also inserted like ('ABC', X).

Is there any significance of this architecture?

And also where can I find the case study of common large scale custom built ERP system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are asking why would someone replace IDs that are unique only for a table

- TABLE clients (id_client AUTO_INCREMENT, name, address)
- TABLE products (id_product AUTO_INCREMENT, name, price)
- TABLE orders (id_order AUTO_INCREMENT, id_client, date)
- TABLE order_details (id_order_detail AUTO_INCREMENT, id_order, id_product, amount)

with global IDs that are unique within the whole database

- TABLE objects (id AUTO_INCREMENT)
- TABLE clients (id_object, name, address)
- TABLE products (id_object, name, price)
- TABLE orders (id_object, id_object_client, date)
- TABLE order_details (id_object, id_object_order, id_object_product, amount)

(Of course you could still call these IDs id_product etc. rather than id_object. I only used the name id_object for clarification.)

The first approach is the common one. When inserting a new row into a table you get the next available ID for the table. If two sessions want to insert at the same time, one must wait briefly.

The second approach hence leads to sessions waiting for their turn everytime they want to insert data, no matter what table, as they all get their IDs from the objects table. The big advantage is that when exporting data, you have global references. Say you export orders and the recipient tells you: "We have problems with your order details 12345. There must be something wrong with your data". Wouldn't it be great, if you could tell them "12345 is not an order detail ID, but a product ID. Do you have problems importing the product or can you tell me an order detail ID this is about?" rather than looking at an order detail record for hours that happens to have the number 12345, while it had nothing to do with the issue, really?

That said, it might be a better choice to use the first approach and add a UUID to all tables you'd use for external communication. No fight for the next ID and still no mistaken IDs in communication :-)

Comment: thanks for your insight. I came up with a new approach. I am going to add a middle wear to the system that would be active only when I need to debug the system which was the primary reason for using the central ID approach. and when not needed the middle wear would be turned off. how is this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is the common strategy used in datawarehouse to track the the batch number after successful or failure of dataloading, in case the loading of the data got failed you will say something like 'ABC' , 'Batch_num' and  'Error_Code' in the batch control table, so your further logic of loading can decide on what do with failure and can easily track the loading, in case if you want to recheck we can archive the data. This ID's are usually generated by a sequence in data base, in one word it is mostly used for *monitoring* purposes.

You can refer this [link](https://datawarehouseandautomation.wordpress.com/etl-job-control-table-and-its-implementaion-for-incremental-load/) for more details

Comment: thanks, It was a great resource. need to work on warehouse though.

Answer (score 0):

The downside to such a design is that it puts a tremendous load on the central table when inserting new data. It is a built-in bottleneck.

Some "advantages" are:

1. Any resource id that is found anywhere in the system can be readily identified, regardless of type.
2. If there is any text in the table (such as a name or description), then it is all centralized facilitating multi-lingual support.
3. Foreign key references can work across multiple types.

The third is not really an advantage, because it comes with a downside:  the inability to specify a specific type for foreign key references.

Answer (score 0):

There are several more techniques, each with pros and cons.  But let me start by pointing out two techniques that hit a brick wall at some point in scaling up.  Let's assume you have billions of items, probably scattered across multiple server either by sharding or other techniques.

Brick wall #1:  UUIDs are handy because clients can create them without having to ask some central server for values.  But UUIDs are very random.  This means that, in most situations, each reference incurs a disk hit because the id is unlikely to be cached.

Brick wall #2:  Ask a central server, which has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` under the covers to dole out ids.  I watched a social media site that was doing nothing but collecting images for sharing crash because of this.  That's in spite of there being a server whose sole purpose is to hand out numbers.

Solution #1:

Here's one (of several) solutions that avoids most problems:  Have a central server that hands out 100 ids at a time.  After a client uses up the 100 it has been given, it asks for a new batch.  If the client crashes, some of the last 100  are "lost".  Oh, well; no big deal.

That solution is upwards of 100 times as good as brick wall #2.  And the ids are much less random than those for brick wall #1.

Solution #2:  Each client can generate its own 64-bit, semi-sequential, ids.  The number includes a version number, some of the clock, a dedup-part, and the client-id.  So it is roughly chronological (worldwide), and guaranteed to be unique.  But still have good locality of reference for items created at about the same time.

Note:  My techniques can be adapted for use by individual tables or as an uber-number for all tables.  That distinction may have been your 'real' question.  (The other Answers address that.)

Comment: thanks for your insight. I came up with a new approach. I am going to add a middle wear to the system that would be active only when I need to debug the system which was the primary reason for using the central ID approach. and when not needed the middle wear would be turned off. how is this approach?

Comment: @rajdhanani - Leave the middle-ware in place.  Use to do more things than just debugging.  I'll let you think about it.  Such a "layer" can facilitate radical changes -- such as a major schema change; sharding; other things that would be disruptive without code already in place to help.